# Coldfusion 11 Application server stops automatically in windows 10

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, iis-10, coldfusion-administrator

I'm working on **ColdFusion 11** project with IIS server. I'm facing a problem with the Coldfusion services. The ColdFusion 11 **application server automatically stops suddenly**, and **after restarting** the service it **works for 2 minutes and again shuts down**.

The status on the Services shows 'Running' but when I cross-check with the administrator its already stopped. While restarting the service it also throws an Error:1053. I have tried with the registry editing and adding the 'ServicesPipeTimeout' but it didn't work. Please help to resolve the automatic shutting down of the service.

Comment: Please check the log files in `\ColdFusion11\cfusion\logs`.

Comment: Do you have sufficient memory allocated to the JVM? Do any of the log files for the application server have mentions of memory errors? Does the event viewer show any errors when the service fails?

Comment: Hi, Alex and John Sieber, I have Minimum JVM Heap size 512 and Maximum JVM Heap size 4096 with added JVM arguments  -XX:MaxPermSize=768m. Moreover I have gone through the logs as suggested and found the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Can you please suggest me how much memory should be enough for cf11 for the application service? 
Thanks

Comment: @alex Hi, I have Minimum JVM Heap size 512 and Maximum JVM Heap size 4096 with added JVM arguments -XX:MaxPermSize=768m. Moreover I have gone through the logs as suggested and found the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Can you please suggest me how much memory should be enough for cf11 for the application service? Thanks

Comment: @JohnSieber Hi, I have Minimum JVM Heap size 512 and Maximum JVM Heap size 4096 with added JVM arguments -XX:MaxPermSize=768m. Moreover I have gone through the logs as suggested and found the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Can you please suggest me how much memory should be enough for cf11 for the application service? Thanks.

Comment: @jeet do you have code that could be consuming a large amount of memory in a single request? 4GB is a large amount of memory, but depending on what your app is doing, you might have a situation where you are consuming it all in a single request. Are you looping through a large dataset or in a single request? I'd try to find the code that is running right before the out of memory error to see if you can isolate the issue.

Comment: @JohnSieber, Thanks for the reply, I have increased the JVM heap memory to  
 8194 and it worked.